# Hamiltonian trajectory stays in the typical set?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I'm currently studying Hamiltonian MCMC by reading Betancourt's 2014 and Neal's 2011 pedagogical papers, but I still don't understand why following a Hamiltonian trajectory for our proposed update guarantees us staying in the typical set, given that we started in the typical set.

I understand that this is essentially the entire point of introducing Hamiltonian dynamics in our MCMC framework, as we would like to sample from the typical set, and, in doing so, utilize symplectic integrators to trace an approximate Hamiltonian trajectory in our augmented parameter space for a set amount of time from which we marginalize out the momentum variables and obtain our updated state... but I fail to see why it works.

Also, I read in Neal's paper the proofs of how any Hamiltonian trajectory is reversible, preserves the value of the Hamiltonian, and preserves the volume in phase-space -- all of which are extremely desirable properties for showing an H-MCMC retains an invariant joint distribution (with a MH correction for approximate trajectories, of course). I refuse to believe that the Hamiltonian just happens to (1) allow us to remain within the typical set AND (2) possess such nice characteristics that make the MCMC algorithm tractable.

Is it because the typical set itself coincides with (an infinite number of) level sets (i.e. concentric layers of Hamiltonian trajectories) from which we attempt to jump between? If so, is there any explicit proof of this statement? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.