# Relation between typical set and stationary condition in MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, stationarity

In Betancourt's paper ["A Conceptual Introduction to Hamiltonian Monte Carlo"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02434), I don't quite see the relation between imposing the stationary condition on the Markov Chain and finding and staying in the typical set.

The paper says: *"So long as this condition holds, at every initial point the Markov transition will concen-trate towards the typical set. Consequently, no matter where we begin in parameter space the corresponding Markov chain will eventually drift into, and then across, the typical set"*. The stationary condition is

$$\pi(q)=\int_{\mathcal{Q}}\mathrm{d}q'\pi(q')\mathbb{T}(q|q')$$

And $dq'\pi(q')$ represents the "mass" of the probability (volume times density). But I don't see why this is happening, why the stationary condition takes you to the typical set and you remain there.

Similar question that went unanswered: [Hamiltonian trajectory stays in the typical set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566707/hamiltonian-trajectory-stays-in-the-typical-set)